# Pass Value as parameter from ngDialog to another controller

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

Below is my code snippet

```
$scope.openrights = function (userid) {
  $scope.valid = userid;
  ngDialog.open({
    template: 'views/rightsassignment.html',
    controller: 'RightsCtrl',
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default ngdialog-theme-custom',
    scope: $scope
  });
};
```

Problem I am having is --- I could not pass the 'valid' scoped value to controller RightsCtrl.

scope: $scope passes the value only to html template mentioned as intepolated value {{valid}}.

How to pass the value 'valid' as parameter to RightsCtrl as $state.params.valid ?

Any Help would be appreciated

I have a state in app.js as

```
  .state('companyadmin.rightsassignment', {
    url: '/rightsassignment/:valid',
    templateUrl: 'views/rightsassignment.html',
    controller: 'RightsCtrl',
    title: 'Welcome Company Admin'

  })
```

Comment: why did you make a separate state for ng-dialog? i have used ng-dialog successfully without making state and still passing parameter. i was able to access $scope.valid inside dialog controller.

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: i meant when you share $scope between dialog and parent controller , all the parent controller $scope variables are accessible in  dialog in same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the parameter as query param to that state or maintain a variable in rootScope.

```
$rootScope.isValid = false;
```

Change this value isValid in your `ngDialog` controller accordingly.

As `$rootScope` is available in all the controllers, you should be able to use it.

**Edit:** I see that you have a path param :valid in your state. You should be passing your `valid` valid to that state when you are transitioning from modal to state.

```
$state.go("companyadmin.rightsassignment", { "valid": true }
```

Comment: Could you please give a snippet of your answer

Comment: using $rootScope to pass data is not recommended since it populates namespace. you can read more about it here :- https://www.quora.com/Is-it-preferable-to-use-rootscope-in-AngularJS-to-pass-data-from-one-controller-to-another

Comment: It is true that it is not recommended. Updated my answer with how you can pass it as a state param.

Answer (score 0):

Check This - you need to pass variables with data property

```
$scope.valid = userid;
ngDialog.open({ template: 'templateId',
className: 'ngdialog-theme-default ngdialog-theme-custom',
data: $scope.valid,
controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {

        // controller logic

                alert($scope.valid);


    }]
    });
```